# openapi-generator asciidoc limits parameter columns, omits type

Tags: openapi-generator, asciidoc, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Is there a way to specify which columns appear in the Parameters section? For example I would like to use Schema/type instead of Pattern.

My configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/target/openapi.json</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>asciidoc</generatorName>
                <configOptions>
                    <useIntroduction>true</useIntroduction>
                </configOptions>
                <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here's the relevant source snippet:

```
 /myapi/{resourceId}:
    get:
      tags:
      - Api Operations
      summary: Get a widget
      description: Get a widget by its resource id
      operationId: findOne
      parameters:
      - name: resourceId
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: affiliateId
        in: header
        required: false
        schema:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          default: 256
```

And the relevant output snippet:

```
====== Header Parameters

[cols="2,3,1,1,1"]
|===
|Name| Description| Required| Default| Pattern

| affiliateId
|  
| -
| 256
| 

|===
```

Instead of the "Pattern" column I would like it show something like Schema along with the value of integer and/or int64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by editing the mustache templates:

After cloning the openapi-generator project, I found and copied the following two files from `src/main/resources/asciidoc-documentation` under modules ([link](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/asciidoc-documentation)): `params.mustache` and `param.mustache`, to my own project under `/src/main/resources/openapi`.

Then I opened `params.mustache` and did a find-and-replace from "Pattern" to "Data Type".

Similarly in `param.mustache` I replaced "{{{pattern}}}" with "{{dataType}}"

Then in the maven pom file plugin config for `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` I added the following element under the `configuration` element:

```
<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi</templateDirectory>
```

Running mvn clean compile resulted in the desired output:

```
[cols="2,3,1,1,1"]
|===
|Name| Description| Required| Default| Data Type

| affiliateId
|  
| -
| 256
| Long
```

Note: To arrive at the right model field name, I enabled debug under the configuration element: `<verbose>true</verbose>` then issued the command (something like): `mvn org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.3.0:generate@my-execution-id -pl mysubmodule -X -l out.txt`; open out.txt and search for "headerParams" or "affiliateId" and find the field name corresponding to data type, in my case there were "dataType" and "dataFormat" of which I chose the former.

Also note that I did not need to copy `index.mustache` or `model.mustache` etc. to my project, only the two template files mentioned above.